# Issue using Adapter and viewHolder (crash)

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-viewholder

I'm quite new into java and Android, and I'm stuck right now. My goal is to do a menu to explore a catalog. I've just done the first part, but the app crash when i launch it. I think that due to the pictures, I think i havn't understood everything. 
Here's my source code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bitmap[] tabImg = {
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.powerload),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.striplineattenuator),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smd_resistor),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.uhf),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.impedancematcher),
    };
    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<Produit> produit = genererProduit();
        ProduitAdapter adapter = new ProduitAdapter(MainActivity.this, produit);
        mListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
    }

    private List<Produit> genererProduit() {
        List<Produit> produit = new ArrayList<Produit>();
        produit.add(new Produit("aaa", "L'intégralité des xxx", tabImg[1]));
        produit.add(new Produit("bbb", "L'intégralité des xxx",tabImg[2]));
        produit.add(new Produit("ccc", "L'intégralité des xxx",tabImg[3]));
        produit.add(new Produit("ddd", "L'intégralité des xxx",tabImg[4]));
        produit.add(new Produit("eee", "Tous les autres produits xxx",tabImg[5]));
        return produit;
    }
}

-----------------------------------

public class Produit {
    private String nom;
    private String codeProduit;
    private Bitmap image;

    public Produit(String nom, String codeProduit,Bitmap image) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.codeProduit = codeProduit;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public String getCodeProduit() {
        return codeProduit;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public void setSurname(String codeProduit) {
        this.codeProduit = codeProduit;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------
public class ProduitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Produit> {
    //tweets est la liste des models à afficher
    public ProduitAdapter(Context context, List<Produit> produit) {
        super(context, 0, produit);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        }

        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if (viewHolder == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            viewHolder.codeProduit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codeProduit);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Produit produit = getItem(position);

        //il ne reste plus qu'à remplir notre vue
        viewHolder.nom.setText(produit.getNom());
        viewHolder.codeProduit.setText(produit.getCodeProduit());
        viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(produit.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }
}

    public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView nom;
    public TextView codeProduit;
    public ImageView image;
}
```

Any help is welcome, i'm quite sure that it's for a stupid thing but again, i'm quite new to this. Thanks for your help and advices!
Seedbarrett

Comment: move the initialization of `tabImg` in `onCreate`

Comment: Some random advice, Put a bunch of verbose logs inside of your code to figure out which method is crapping out. I usually do a log output for "OnCreate()" "OnResume()" just to denote that each method is called. Also if you think it's your drawable (pictures), find a super small picture or bitmap and use that as a test case. I've found problems when I use bitmaps that are too big. There are finite memory restrictions for drawables. Also please provide your logcat output from adb.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.diconex.catalogue, PID: 1952
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.diconex.catalogue/com.example.diconex.catalogue.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)

Comment: I already use picture with a 100*68 definition. I've tried to put [tag:tabImg] on[tag: onCreate], but it seems it's not better. I've tried like this:

 @ Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bitmap[] tabImg = {
                [...] 
        };
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

and so on. I'm a neebie again, even if something sound stupid it could make me learn more :D

Comment: It's caused by a pointer wich return Null, and `tabImg` is faulty. I've finaly directly put   `  produit.add(new Produit("aaa", "L'intégralité des xxx", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.powerload))); ` to not use array, and its working at least..